# iOS Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Okay,

I am relatively new to Objective-C.  I am trying to build a basic Table View that will load data from my local server.  The data load script works, by itself, however when I try to implement it with the Table View, the App crashes giving the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error message.  I try calling the retrieveData with nothing in it and it still crashes.  This is probably a simple fix.  Can someone please help.

```
2013-11-10 19:35:38.033 NewApp[4542:70b] -[TableViewController retreiveData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109265250
2013-11-10 19:35:38.036 NewApp[4542:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TableViewController retreiveData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109265250'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010188f795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001015f2991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101920bad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010188109d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101880c48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   NewApp                            0x00000001000020fb -[TableViewController viewDidLoad] + 107
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100340fe4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 562
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001003411bd -[UIViewController view] + 29
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001002888c7 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100288bd5 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 275
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100291ca2 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001002500c8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1449
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000100253be8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000100264aab -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3092
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000100264f1e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001002552be _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 618
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103997bb6 _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010399767d PurpleEventCallback + 35
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101811819 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018115ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010183aab3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101839f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001002534bd -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000100255043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    24  NewApp                            0x0000000100001fa3 main + 115
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101f1e5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: The IDE is called "Xcode", not "XCODE"; but it is irrelevant to the question anyway (the problem is not related to its usage, the problem is in your code). And the exception message tells you clearly what the problem is: the `TableViewController` class does not implement the `retreiveData` method. You probably meant `retrieveData`, and as such, you should have gotten a warning, which you apparently didn't pay attention to.

Comment: @H2CO3 But warnings and error messages are so boring, posting on SO it so fun! Understanding what Xcode is and the difference between it and Object-C, really, that would take learning. Get real. :-)

Comment: @Zaph :) I never give up. We don't need more lazy people in the (not-only-iOS) programming community. There's already enough confusion. Look, I managed to learn what I've know about iOS by doing nothing but searching Google and SO. By going through tutorials. By **thinking and using my common sense.** That's a reasonable expectation from anyone who will want to call himself an iOS developer.

Comment: Your sarcasm is unappreciated.  I can spell the IDE name with Caps or not.  The ultimate problem is unrelated to the spelling error that you pointed out.  But thanks anyways.

Comment: @H2CO3 Seriously: I am so discouraged by so much I see here and also by so many developers I meet in person.

Comment: @scriptdiddy The error message "'-[TableViewController retreiveData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" clearly states that there is no method `retreiveData` in the class `TableViewController`. That is the problem. Show some code and perhaps someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be quite simple, you call `retreiveData`, as you've pointed out, but according to the Objective-C runtime, no such method exists and thus the invocations fails and your app crashes. Make sure that the method actually exists (it probably is just a typo and you meant `retrieveData`?!)

Comment: @scriptdiddy Show some code!